# Midnight Commander Exit from Working Directory doesn't return to same directory in Terminal

Tags: terminal, mac

Upon exit from midnight commander(MC), terminal returns to default directory(users/username) instead of working directory in MC. 
Had tried creating

```
alias mc='. /usr/share/mc/bin/mc-wrapper.sh
```

but it’s not working.

Comment: I assume you are following the instructions in https://ptspts.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-make-midnight-commander-exit-to.html? What exactly do you mean by not working? Does the alias not work, does it not remain defined after you restart your shell, does it not change directory?

Comment: In MC, say i'm on Desktop(/users/abc/Desktop), then upon exit from MC i need the terminal to be in same Working Directory(/users/abc/Desktop) instead of Default one(/users/abc)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqhoPBkS0KE&pbjreload=10 from 7.48 min

Comment: It's clear what the alias *should* to, the trick is to figure out why it doesn't work as expected on your machine. So can you please describe in more detail how you start Midnight Commander and what exactly does not work?